# NetSuite SS 2 and Saved searches

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

you guys have been really helpful, and I truly appreciate it. What would be the appropriate way to return a saved search in SS 2.0? I am writing an app that will pull saved search turn into csv and sFtp to another system. The component I am currently involved in is the data request. What is the accepted approach to pull that data? PS. I did look at other postings but they were specific to a certain problem, it also looks like the are  using the ODBC adaptor and writing queries, which is fine too but is there more than one way? and "normally" what is the first approach. Sorry for the diatribe!

thanks again

Comment: The basic answer would be to use the N/search module. Normally you should do at least a bit of work before posting a question. i.e. actually cut some code and see where you get stopped. Then post a specific question to help you get around the stoppage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how to get the results of a saved search in SS 2.0 . From there you can turn it into a CSV and SFTP it. Good Luck!

```
require(['N/search'], function(SEARCHMODULE){
    var savedSearchId = 'customsearch_mySavedSearch';
    var mySearch = SEARCHMODULE.load(savedSearchId);
    var resultset = mySearch.run();
    var results = resultset.getRange(0, 1000);
    for(var i in results){
        var result = results[i];
        for(var k in result.columns){
            log.debug('Result is ' + result.getValue(result.columns[k]));     //Access result from here
        }
    }
});
```